# python - creating a function that returns all caller function arguments as a kwargs dictionary

Tags: python, object, arguments, init

My goal is to create a function that can be a "watermark" or an "audit trail" of how an object was created.

Suppose that I have the following in a module called my_module:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4='some_string'):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        ... # and so on
```

I'm hoping to do something like:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4='some_string'):
        self.inputs = my_function(...)
```

and have that be the same thing as if I did:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4='some_string'):
        self.inputs = {
            'arg1': arg1,
            'arg2': arg2, 
            'arg3': None,
            ...# and so on
            }
```

Ideally I'd like to put this function "my_function" in a separate module called "tools".

What I've tried so far is in a module called "tools":

```
def my_function():
    caller_stack = inspect.stack()
    caller_function_string = str.join('.', caller_stack[1][0].f_back.f_code.co_names[:-1])
    caller_function = eval(caller_function_string)
    return caller_function.__code__.co_varnames[:caller_function.__code__.co_argcount]
```

The idea is that if called inside the `__init__` function, the `caller_function_string` would be `"my_module.my_class.__init__"`, which is indeed working.  Then I would eval this string to get the function handle.  Using the function handle, I can figure out what all the argument names are in this function, and then create a dictionary from this.  The issue is that I can't run `eval(caller_function_string` because the "tools" module does not import "my_module".

Surely there is a better way to do this?  I could just save every `arg1`, `arg2`,  explicitly in the `__init__` but I figured this function would be quite handy to not type those lines of code every time I create a new object (and have to add a line if I add a new argument, etc).

Comment: I'm not sure why defining `my_function` is any simpler than just defining the `dict` explicitly in `__init__`.

Comment: For one class, it's not bad to define the dictionary explicitly.  But going forward if I create multiple classes, it would be nice to just call `my_function` and know that it will handle any arguments that class takes in.  Additionally, if I modify the class to support more arguments, I wouldn't have to go to `__init__` and add it explicitly to the dictionary.